# Apex Commandbutton does not fire actionmethod every time

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have an apex page which relies heavily on rerendering certain parts of the page. The issue is that when I click on a commandbutton, normally it calls its action method, and rerenders a part of the page, however, it only works about half the time. On the other occasions the action method does not fire. (Something still happens, because it creates a debug log)

The confusing thing about it is that it happens seemingly randomly (e.g. It works, I reload the page, then it doesn't work, while nothing changed)

Unfortunately I don't have permission to post the code, but any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the "reRender" attribute set to?  For those itenms, how are the "rendered" attributes set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by an actionsupport tag inside of a commandbutton which I think should be fine, but it wasn't. I deleted the actionsupport, edited the button itself to contain the rerender and action attributes, and now it works.